# Updating Database Based on DropDownlist Selection

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using Grid-view to show data and want to update database Quantity column on dropdownlist selected index change. Again to be clear i don't want to use any update button it should take action as dropdownlist selected item changes. Code for Grid-view is

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    DataKeyNames="Cart_id" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField DeleteText="Remove" ShowDeleteButton="True" 
            ButtonType="Image" DeleteImageUrl="~/images/remove-to-cart-icon.jpg" 
            HeaderText="Remove" >
        <ControlStyle Height="30px" Width="50px" />
        </asp:CommandField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cart_id" InsertVisible="False" 
            SortExpression="Cart_id" Visible="False">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Cart_id") %>'></asp:Label>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Cart_id") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Product_name" HeaderText="Product_name" 
            SortExpression="Product_name" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Product_cost" HeaderText="Product_cost" 
            SortExpression="Product_cost" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity" SortExpression="Quantity">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Quantity") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
                    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Quantity", "{0}") %>' 
                    onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                    CommandName="Change" AutoPostBack="True">
                    <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:shoppingConnectionString2 %>" 
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Cart] WHERE [Cart_id] = @Cart_id" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Cart] WHERE ([User_id] = @User_id)" 
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Cart] ([User_id], [Product_id], [Product_name], [Product_cost], [Quantity]) VALUES (@User_id, @Product_id, @Product_name, @Product_cost, @Quantity)" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Cart] SET [User_id] = @User_id, [Product_id] = @Product_id, [Product_name] = @Product_name, [Product_cost] = @Product_cost, [Quantity] = @Quantity WHERE [Cart_id] = @Cart_id">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Cart_id" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="User_id" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Product_id" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Product_name" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Product_cost" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Quantity" Type="Int32" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="User_id" QueryStringField="uid" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="User_id" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Product_id" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Product_name" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Product_cost" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Quantity" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Cart_id" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I want to get the cartid value to be stored in a variable in backend when dropdownlist value is changed, so that i can update my database.

Comment: so what is problem here , is it not updating now?

Comment: I have not yet added any code when dropdownlist item changes. I need that code.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's simply a matter of calling SQLDataSource1.Update () in the Load event.

From MSDN regarding SQLDataSource.Update () method:
"The Update method is automatically called by the GridView, DetailsView, and FormView controls during postback if the data has been changed. For data that has been changed in other controls, the Update method can be explicitly called on postback during the Load event."

It appears you've got everything wired up correctly. So, I would try this within you Page_Load event.

```
void Page_Load (Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!IsPostBack) {
        // non post back stuff
    }
    else {
        SQLDataSource1.Update ();
    }
}
```

I would take out the CommandName="Change" from the DropDownList tag also. I don't think that's doing anything, and may be hindering the operation.

If that doesn't work, perhaps try defining the DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged event:

```
void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    SQLDataSource1.Update ();
}
```

Sorry, wish I could be more definitive on this, but I have no way to test this right now on my development machine.

Hope this helps.

Tom

Comment: thanks for trying but upon postback my database is not getting updated but the value of dropdownlist again getting selected to 1.